# Jquery show/hide in another page

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have 2 html page

**in Page 1** there is 2 links "link1" & "link2"

**in Page 2** there is also 2 links "link1" & "link2" as well as 2 `<div id="pan1">` & `<div id="pan2">` `<div id="pan1">`

& `<div id="pan2">` is working as show/hide with jquery

I want when user click on the link1 in page1 it will go to page 2 and div"id=pan1" will show and when user click on the link2 in page1 it will go to page 2 and div"id=pan2" will show.

here is the html code for page 1

```
<ul class="linkList">
<li><a href="#pan1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#pan2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the code for page 2

html

```
<ul class="linkList">
<li><a href="#pan1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#pan2">2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="pan1" class="switchgroup" style="padding:10px; background-color:#060">div 1</div>
<div id="pan2" class="switchgroup" style="padding:10px; background-color:#936">div 2</div>
```

css

```
#pan1, #pan2{
    display:none;   
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pan1').show();
    $('.linkList li:first-child a').addClass('active');
    $('.linkList li a').click(function() {
        var tabDivId = this.hash;                              

        $('.linkList li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        //console.log(tabDivId);
        $('.switchgroup').hide();
        $(tabDivId).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: u working with .net or php by any chance?

Comment: im sorry i dont got more time thats why i post this as a comment but you can check this jquery plugin, https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin you can use sessions to do this what you asking for. hope this helps you on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a general idea of how to do it. Please note I haven't tested this code so it might have some minor issues.

Page 1 HTML:

```
<ul class="linkList">
    <li><a href="page2.html#pan1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html#pan2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Page 2 HTML:

```
<ul class="linkList">
    <li><a href="#pan1" class="panlink">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pan2" class="panlink">2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="pan1" class="switchgroup">div 1</div>
<div id="pan2" class="switchgroup">div 2</div>
```

Page 2 JS:

```
$(function() {
    var anc = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
    $('#' + anc + '.switchgroup').show();

    $('a.panlink').click(function() {
        $('.switchgroup').hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    });
});
```

Page 2 CSS:

```
.switchgroup { display: none; }
```

Comment: yes its working fine ...but I want when user direct go to page2, div 1 will display first

Comment: @SonasishRoy Can you expand on that?

Comment: I want when user direct land on page2 then div1 will display by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create function to be implemented on other pages, but in your case you can use parameters:

when you provide the second page's (redirect to the second page) add a query string parameter, or by form's parameters (Post/Get). and on JQuery's ready function add your hide/show code.

from where I understood your question, this should do the work.