# Toggling two divs with the click of one link from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a page that compares two products side-by-side. So far, I have a single-post page for each individual product. On that single-post page is a set of links that allow the user to select a different product to compare it to.

On the comparison page, I was able to figure out how to toggle the first div that pulls the information from the original post, but how do I toggle the second div too?

Here's the code I have on the single-post page (I used [Jquery show/hide in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428818/jquery-show-hide-in-another-page) as a reference):

```
<ul class="linkList">
    <li><a href="product-comparison/#product1">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="product-comparison/#product2">Product 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the code I have on the comparison page:

```
<ul class="linkList">
    <li><a href="#product1" class="panlink">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#product2" class="panlink">Product 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="product1" class="switch">Product 1</div>
<div id="product2" class="switch">Product 2</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(function() {
    var anc = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
    $('#' + anc + '.switch').show();

    $('a.panlink').click(function() {
        $('.switch').hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    });
});
```

and my CSS:

```
.switch { display: none; }
```

I've searched high and low, and I can't seem to find an answer for this - only answers from toggling one div.

Let me know if you need clarification - thanks! :)

Comment: can you clarify your end goal slightly more? reading this twice gave me nothing

Comment: why not list all your products on the same page, and show there differences in a grid/column layout so that it can be seen all at one shot, rather than clicking to show comparison data...?  And if the grid is too long, use media queries or a jquery plugin to compact the table data to be responsive.

Comment: @abc123 - I'm trying to display the comparison between the two products on a separate page. On the comparison page, it'll call a div that contains the information from the original product, and in another div on the comparison page, it'll show the information from the product I selected from the list on the single-post page. Basically, I want one URL that will open two divs on another page. I'm just not sure how to go about adding to what I have to make this work.

Comment: @BrittanyLayneRapheal right without knowing your backend language or architecture (restFUL api, or only viewState passing) we can't just write random code for you.

Comment: @Blackhawk - unfortunately, I can't do it all on one page. I'm recreating a Wordpress theme for a client, and the formatting, layout, and functionality has to be the same.

Comment: @abc123 - It doesn't even need to be adding on to what I have. If there's another method of doing this, I'd be happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that may benefit you.

If you every want to compare any of your relative web pages into your current page, use jQuery's AJAX process within an `.on('click', 'class-of-product', function() {});` approach to pull data onto your current page.  You may need to also use the `filter()` method to reduce the amount of set elements you are pulling from your product pages.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep this in mind for if I can't find a method of generating the product info on a separate page. :)